# How to Modify permanently a wordpress plugin and adding a function inside

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

I have to add a JavaScript function on a button click inside a plugin, i've tried but every time i update the plugin the function get removed how can i add permanently the function?

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins that allow you to add code that won't be erased on upgrade.  [This](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) is one.

If you have many customizations, you may want to consider [creating your own plugin](https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/how-to-create-your-first-wordpress-plugin/)

Comment: The problem is that i need to add a onclick function inside the button in the plugin, I can't do that with an external plugin

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the plugin update using filter.

```
add_filter('site_transient_update_plugins', 'remove_update_notification');
function remove_update_notification($value) {
     unset($value->response[ plugin_basename(__FILE__) ]);
     return $value;
}
```

Because everytime you update the plugin it will replace the plugin files with new one.